# Error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: laravel

llevo todo el santo dia con una cosa que no doy con el problema: estoy tratando de instalar toastr para mostrar notificaciones, tengo un proyecto limpio de laravel 8 con el plugin instalado, tengo un controlador que en el index deberia redireccionarme a una vista y mostrar el alerta, pero resulta que me da error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS en la redireccion, ya que si hago un return a la vista, me muestra el contenido de la vista (un mensaje: HOLA), no se la verdad que es el problema, es un proyecto limpio con solo una ruta:

```
route::get('/prueba', [ServicioController::class, 'index'])->name('testing2');
```

El controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Alert;

class ServicioController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(){
        toast('Your Post as been submited!','success');
        return redirect()->route('testing2');
    }
}
```

Llevo horas leyendo foros, comentarios pero no puedo resolver el problema.

Saludos a todos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes en tu función es un bucle infinito, ya que al entrar a `/prueba` en la función index al final haces una redirección a la ruta de nombre `testing2` en tu archivo `web.php` que es el mismo enlace de `/prueba`, por lo que es un bucle.

Para imprimir una vista es colocar al final de tu función un `return view()` y la ruta a tu vista, ejemplo:

```
public function index(){
    toast('Your Post as been submited!','success');
    return view('home.index')
}
```

Suponiendo que tu archivo de blade esté en el path `resources/views/home/index.blade.php`